# Changing the color of a div based on a mysql field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I will try to give you as much detail as possible so you understand what I'm thinking.

I'm working on a little web app written mainly in php. I have one table in mysql with one row that has a username field, password field, and a "state" field.

The web portion 1 page with username and password fields and a submit button. When the username and password are correct it turns the state to on. This is supposed to represent a generator that you have to keep on.

I then have a cronjob run a script every 10 minutes to turn the state off. This is for a little competition I'm in. We are supposed to monitor the generator site and if the generator turns off, we have to put in a username and password and turn it back on. So all of that stuff functions.

My question is that I want to have a small colored square be green when the generator is on and change to red when the generator is off. I want to be able to do that without reloading the page. So if I'm staring at the page and state changes to off it will just turn red.

I've kind of looked into AJAX (Since I'm assuming that is what I'll need to use) But didn't find examples of something similar to this. If anyone could, will you kind of show me how you would do that with a brief syntax example? The help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div id="generator-state"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#generator-state { height: 100px; width: 100px;}
#generator-state.on { background: green; }
#generator-state.off { background: red; }
```

**jQuery**

Make an AJAX call to the server. Parse the data object that's returned for the status of the generator (`data.state`), and use that value to set the class on the `#generator-state` element.

`db.php` queries your MySQL database.

`setInterval()` runs the AJAX every 10 minutes.

```
function fetchState() {
  $.get('/path/to/db.php', function(data) { 
    $('#generator-state').removeClass('on off').addClass(data.state === 'on' ? 'on' : 'off');
  });
}

setInterval(fetchState, 10 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got all that in. I did the javascript in a different file and linked it to the page. Is there a header or anything that needs to go in the javascript file? All I have in that file is what you put. Also what exactly needs to be in the db.php? I'll give you what I have:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';

$db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to mysql: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database,$db_server) or die("Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT state FROM gen WHERE user='ccdc'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>
```